# Where could I post a question about a possible invention idea?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have this idea for an alternative to using water to clean and wash dishes and/or even surfaces and wondered where's the best place to place such a query to see if it or something similar exists already.

My idea is to use a self cleaning gel of some sort that you have in your kitchen sink and you place your dishes etc into and it removes any dirt, grease and bacteria! Method of cleaning action could be number of things from super hydrophobicity of the gel pulling dirt off the surface of the dishes when you remove them form the gel and the gel could have some inherent biodegrading and antimicrobial properties to facilitate cleansing.

There doesn't appear to be a Stack Exchange site relevant to invention or speculative ideas.

Answer (score 7):

The site [Ask Patents](http://patents.stackexchange.com) allows questions about

> Prior art for a US patent application, whether anyone knows of any that might exist, or whether something you’ve found would qualify

according to its [help centre](https://patents.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

You could use that to find out whether your idea has been previously patented in the US and presumably if so, by whom.